# Export errors and warnings from all event logs using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, command, get-eventlog, get-winevent

I am using the following code to export errors and warnings from all event logs into one text file.
It works but is very slow and some of the messages are truncated. I wondered if there was a more efficent way of coding it. I'm new to powershell so would appreciate your thoughts or ideas.

```
$Logs = Get-Winevent -ListLog *

foreach ($Log in $Logs) {
Get-WinEvent -LogName $Log.LogName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ?{$_.Level -eq 1 -or $_.Level -eq 2 -or $_.Level -eq 3} | Sort-Object ProviderName, TimeCreated -descending  | Out-String -Width 1000 | Format-Table -AutoSize | Tee-Object -file "c:\common\logs\Eventlog_Export.log" -Append
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me about 30 seconds.  You can filter by date too.

```
$Logs = Get-Winevent -ListLog *

foreach ($Log in $Logs) {
  Get-WinEvent -filterhashtable @{logname = $Log.LogName; level=1,2,3} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
  select LogName,TimeCreated,Id,LevelDisplayName,Message |
  export-csv -append log.csv
}
```

level=1,2,3 doesn't work over invoke-command for some reason.

Comment: How can I specify a destination and filename for the log?  Sorry to ask such a basic question but I'm learning slowly.

Comment: Ok I added some code to save it just off the top of my head.

Comment: Works great. Thanks